# mysql: update increment sequence number with same number previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table look like this:

**table: fruits**

```
------------
num | fruit
------------
1   | apple
1   | banana
2   | orange
2   | apple
2   | guava
3   | grape
3   | strawberry
4   | blueberry
4   | watermelon
4   | honeydew
4   | apple
```

i want to update the sequence to the number that i choose, example start from 600, i tried something like this:

```
UPDATE fruits
JOIN (SELECT @rank := 600) r
SET num=@rank:=@rank+1;
```

it become:

```
------------
num   | fruit
------------
601   | apple
602   | banana
603   | orange
604   | apple
605   | guava
606   | grape
607   | strawberry
608   | blueberry
609   | watermelon
610   | honeydew
611   | apple
```

**result that i want is:**

```
------------
num   | fruit
------------
621   | apple
621   | banana
622   | orange
622   | apple
622   | guava
623   | grape
623   | strawberry
624   | blueberry
624   | watermelon
624   | honeydew
624   | apple
```

so that previous num with 1 will become 601 and 2 will become 602. Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using `+`?

```
UPDATE fruits
    SET num = num + 600;
```

(In your example, you seem to want `+ 620` rather than `+ 600`.)

Comment: What if I want to start in some random number like 564, how the sequence going to work?

Comment: @Teddybugs . . . You would adjust the `600` to be the appropriate offset.